# Conditonals using c++

Tags: c++

I am coding a simple speeding ticket program and I got it to compile but I am having problems getting it to read my conditions and execute the final part of the program which is calculating the ticket.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int speedTraveled;
    int speedLimit = 55;
    int mischiefSpeed = 75;
    int criminalSpeed = 110;
    
    cout << "How fast were you going? " << "\n";
    cin >> speedTraveled;

    
    if (speedTraveled >= 0 || speedTraveled >= 150)
    {
        if (speedTraveled > speedLimit && speedTraveled > mischiefSpeed)
        {
            int tFormula = ((speedTraveled - speedLimit) * 2) + 50;
            cout << "You were speed bettween 55mph - 75mph your fine is : ", tFormula, '\n';
        }

        else if (speedTraveled > mischiefSpeed && speedTraveled < 110)
        {
            int tFormula = ((speedTraveled - speedLimit) * 5) + 50;
            cout << "Your speed was over 75 mph but less than 110 mph your are being arrested : ", tFormula, '\n';
        }
        else if (speedTraveled >= criminalSpeed)
        {
            int tFormula = ((speedTraveled - speedLimit) * 2) + 50;
            cout << "You were speed over 110 mph your are being arrested : ", tFormula, '\n';
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's some logical inconsistencies here. "If greater than zero...or if greater than 150.." Well that's saying the same thing twice. It's worth double-checking your greater/less than signs here since a lot of them look wrong.

Comment: While it's great to have meaningful names for numbers like `speedLimit = 55` the important thing is to use those labels consistently. You have `110`  and `150` (??) in the comparisons where 110 should be `criminalSpeed`.

Comment: should be  `if (speedTraveled > speedLimit && speedTraveled < mischiefSpeed)`. `|| speedTraveled >= 150` got no effect on code

Comment: @tadman thanks I definitely see the inconsistencies

Answer (score 0):

I tested using the value 150. The first if statement executes because you did not set an upper bound on it. Try setting the second `>` into a `<`. Same thing with the first if statement

```
if (speedTraveled >= 0 || speedTraveled >= 150) // No upper bound
if (speedTraveled >= 0 || speedTraveled <= 150) // Upper bound is 150
```

The fine amounts are not printing because you need an insertion operator (`<<`) between the different data types you are trying to output. `cout` uses syntax different from output functions in other languages.

```
cout << "You were speed between 55mph - 75mph your fine is : ", tFormula, '\n';
cout << "You were speed between 55mph - 75mph your fine is : " << tFormula << endl;
```

You have more if statement typos, but I'm sure you can find the rest.